Mysql SUM inside Left Join return wrong value when using with rollup function
Good Afternoon. I have some problem/missunderstood with rollup function when using LEFT Join statement. the sum from rollup at the end is not like my expected. how i can correct the last sum of result, please see the sample table data from my table
***tb_no_penjualan***

id_no_jual | total_bayar  | created_date
----------------------------------------------
2         | 1024176.00   | 2024-10-23 20:40:10
3         | 520000.00    | 2024-10-23 20:47:39
4         | 241000.00    | 2024-10-23 20:55:26
7         | 346280.00    | 2024-10-24 08:55:22
8         | 957840.00    | 2024-10-24 08:57:49
9         | 534064.00    | 2024-10-24 09:04:32
12        | 731864.00    | 2024-10-24 09:34:06

***tb_det_jual***

id_det_jual | id_no_jual | jumlah_item | total_harga
-----------------------------------------------------
2           | 2          | 2           | 300000.00
3           | 2          | 2           | 50000.00
4           | 3          | 25          | 237500.00
5           | 4          | 2           | 331500.00
6           | 7          | 1           | 150000.00
7           | 7          | 5           | 252200.00
8           | 7          | 5           | 50000.00
9           | 7          | 5           | 100000.00
10          | 7          | 2           | 329800.00
11          | 8          | 3           | 494700.00
12          | 9          | 4           | 201760.00
13          | 12         | 3           | 494700.00
14          | 12         | 5           | 50000.00
15          | 12         | 7           | 140000.00


and the result from that query like this:
SELECT a.id_no_jual,
   date(a.created_date) as tanggal,
   SUM(a.jumlah) as jumlah_item,
   SUM(a.total_harga) AS total_harga,
   b.total_bayar 
FROM pos.tb_det_jual a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_no_jual as id_no_jual, 
        SUM(total_bayar) as total_bayar 
    FROM pos.tb_no_penjualan 
    GROUP BY date(created_date)
 ) as b ON(a.id_no_jual=b.id_no_jual)
GROUP BY date(a.created_date) WITH ROLLUP;

and the result from that query like this:
id_no_jual | tanggal   | jumlah_item | total_harga    | total_bayar
---------------------------------------------------------------
2          |2024-10-23 | 31          | 919000.00      | 1107280.00
7          |2024-10-24 | 40          | 2263160.00     | 2620739.20
7          |Null       | 71 (correct)| 3182160.00(ok) | 2620739.20 (wrong) but (3728019.20)


Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

You should be joining on the value you're grouping by, not some other column.

hi Barmar, so the mean if using WITH Rollup function form other column Join table is imposible right?
